# Is there a dangling modifier in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, modifiers

> "The expression constantly changes *while watching it*".

We are talking about a picture here and this sentence is supposed to mean "*while smb. is watching it*", "*it*" refers to the expression. Is it a dangling modifier? Answers from philologists (or just native speakers who are really good in English) will be much appreciated as our professor and I are having an argument over this sentence. Thank you for your help in advance!

Comment: How do you know it is a picture? When I read this sentence I can't understand at all.

Comment: This is a single sentence from a text about Mona Lisa, it's her facial expression we are talking about. It doesn't really matter here anyway, I just wanted to clarify.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it dangles. When you're using *when* or *while* with just a participle (no subject or finite verb), as in your *while watching it*, the omitted subject should be the same as that of the main clause if you want to avoid dangling.

In this case, that subject of the main clause is *the expression*. But **the expression constantly changes while the expression is watching it* doesn't work, as you see. In reality, the omitted subject is *somebody*, so its omission results in a dangling participle.

In somewhat less formal English, you could use a dangling modifier without eliciting cries of anguish from most readers, but only under certain circumstances. I would say it is sometimes possible with verbs like *using* or *considering*, but in my opinion it sounds wrong in your example. Or perhaps the fact that it comes *after* the main clause makes it more glaring.

Comment: Thank you very much! Sounds like I was right after all. ^^

Comment: Can I also add that the sentence is odd on a number of levels, but I concede it might be better in the full context.  But first, even though it is the Mona Lisa, and even though it's famous for its enigmatic half-smile, I still think you **look at** at the painting (and expression), rather than **watch** it. And secondly, who is making the claim that the expression "constantly changes"? Or is this just a reassertion of its reputation?

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to lose the dangle, you could say ‘the expression constantly changes while watching’. You don’t need the ‘it’.

Although, I think the real problem is, that it says ‘*the* expression’ which is rather ambiguous - is it the expression of the subject of the painting, or of the viewer?

Whereas, if it said ‘*her* expression’ we would know who is who, and what is what, in the sentence.

‘Her expression constantly changes while watching it’. Would be pretty clear - in the context of already knowing the sentence is about ‘the Mona Lisa’.

Or a possibly better form might be:

‘The Mona Lisa - her expression constantly appears to change under the gaze of the viewer’.

And yes - as Cargill commented - you don’t ‘watch’ a painting - you view it or look at it - though, if you were trying to catch a moving expression, then I suppose you might be ‘watching’ - which means ‘observing closely, to see what happens next’.